# Flashing entry door in brick veneer under covered porch

Tags: doors, brick, flashing, veneer

I'm about to install a new pivot door, and I wanted to be sure on the flashing details before I tear down the existing door frame. This home is slab-on-grade with brick veneer; the entry is covered, and there's a 10" rise from the ground to the door sill.

I wanted to add a door pan, however I'm not sure if there's a typical 1" gap between the brick and slab for the lip of the door pan to set into. I've heard that flashing tape can also be used in this situation since there's not a real threat of water entering the home, but I'm skeptical.

Any advice?

[image: Porch]

[image: Door sill]

Comment: Why would you need a 1" gap? Your question is a bit vague. Maybe revise to be more specific.